# De-Nesting Absolute Value Function into Linear Combination of Absolute Value Functions

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, algorithms, mathematics-education

**Context:** In formulating problems for secondary school mathematics teachers (and students) about **absolute value functions**, which we define as functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that send $x \mapsto a|x-h|+k$ for fixed parameters $a, h, k \in \mathbb{R}$, I was able to rewrite the **nested** absolute value function

$$f(x) = \Big||x|-1\Big|$$

as a linear combination of absolute value functions,

$$g(x) = |x+1| + |x-1| - (|x|+1)$$

(You can view the graphs of $f$ and $g$ [**here**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j5rgrj1ihh); although not delved into in this post, my colleagues enjoyed finding similar relationships even when there is a quadratic $x$ term, for example, in the graphs/functions depicted [**here**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wljf0czsyj).)

My **question** is twofold (although the follow-up question depends on the first answer):

> **1.** Is it true that every nested absolute value function (NAVF) or linear combination of NAVFs can be written as a linear combination of AVFs?
>
> **2a.** If not, what is a counterexample, and what criteria must be satisfied for de-nesting to be possible?
>
> **2b.** If so, is there an algorithm for de-nesting, i.e., rewriting an arbitrary NAVF as a linear combination of AVFs?

Pointers to related literature/references would be welcome, even if they do not explicitly answer the questions above. Please edit the questions, title, or tags if you believe it will improve clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\renewcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}} 
\newcommand{\tf}{\widetilde{f}}$

Lemma 3 in [Explicit additive decomposition of norms](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.123.5.491) (which is Lemma 1.2 in the [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00537) of that note) states the following:

> Suppose that $f\colon\R\to\R$ is a convex function such that for some real $k$ there exist finite limits 
>   \begin{equation*}
>  d_+:=d_{f,k;+}:=\lim_{u\to\infty}[f(u)-ku]\quad\text{and}\quad d_-:=d_{f,k;-}:=\lim_{u\to-\infty}[f(u)+ku]. 
> \end{equation*}
>   Then for all $x\in\R$ 
>   \begin{equation*}
>  f(x)=\frac{d_++d_-}2+\frac12\,\int_\R|x-t|\,d f'(t). \tag{1}
> \end{equation*}

As is clear from the short proof, this lemma holds for any absolutely continuous function $f$ with (possibly infinite) limits $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f'(x)$. So, it is easy to see by induction on the nesting depth that the lemma holds for any nested absolute value function.

**Added details:**

For a finite nesting depth, the function $f$ is piecewise-affine: 
\begin{multline*}
 f(x)=(a_1+b_1 x)\ii{x\le t_1}+(a_2+b_2 x)\ii{t_1<x\le t_2}+\dots \\ 
 +(a_n+b_n x)\ii{t_{n-1}<x\le t_n}
+(a_{n+1}+b_{n+1} x)\ii{x>t_n}
\end{multline*}
for some natural $n$, some real "switch points" $t_1<\dots<t_n$, some real $a_i$ and $b_i$'s, and all real $x$, where $\ii\cdot$ denotes the the indicator. 
So, the integral in the lemma reduces to a sum: 
\begin{equation*}
 f(x)=\frac{d_++d_-}2+\frac12\,\sum_1^n|x-t_i|\,\De f'(t_i) \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
for all real $x$, 
where $\De f'(t):=f'(t+)-f'(t-)$, the "jump" of $f'$ at $t$, so that $\De f'(t_i):=b_{i+1}-b_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$.

For the example at the link provided in the comment by the OP, formula (2) is illustrated in this [Mathematica notebook](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ6Woj7ZyF3PLVH86Nz2uavdz11N84K1DFKk) and its [pdf image](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZEWoj7ZCRAmBXtEmWjb56h9hy64EzrxmSV7).

Comment: Could you describe how to use the algorithm in your mentioned proof to de-nest a function such as $$f(x) = \Big|\big|3|x|-1\big| - 4\big|x-1\big|\Big|$$? I know that it is *possible* as can be seen [**here**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lcijaknywk); but, I am not sure how your Lemma 1.2 could accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminDickman :  I have added the details that you requested.

Comment: This is great! It looks like you input an example from an earlier comment (which had mismatched absolute value signs) rather than the $f(x)$ above, but your updated answer is clarifying. ([**Here**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/occci88ll6) is the function you addressed with its input and output.) Thanks!

Comment: I am glad this was helpful.